# Test execution dependency for py_test

Tags: bazel

I am writing an integration-test (`py_test`) for a Python library. Now it only makes sense to run this one if a set of other `py_test` unit-tests have successfully completed.

I could not yet find a way of adding such a testing-dependency in Bazel.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry it is not possible.

An action cannot declare a dependency on a test action.

Maybe you can work around by doing only one test or by adding tags (phase1, phase2):

```
bazel test --test_tag_filter -phase2 //... && bazel test --test_tag_filter phase2 //...
```

Comment: How far is this gone, though? Are there any run dependencies supported yet?

Comment: Right now, Bazel has a fairly strict separation between the phases of the build (compiling vs. execution). We're working on relaxing this so they can be interleaved, but it's a long way off (AFAIK). Theoretically, you could make running the unit test a "build" step (by executing them in a genrule) and then make the output of that a dependency of the integration tests. But that's super hacky, Damien's way is better.